# How do i close a CommPort in RXTX

Tags: java, serial-port, rxtx

I am trying to close a Comm port using this:

```
public synchronized void closeComportButtonActionPerformed(
                java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt)  {

            try {
                twoWaySerCom.disconnect();
            } catch (Exception e) {

                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```

and my disconnect is this:

```
 void disconnect() throws Exception {
    if (serialPort != null) {
        InputStream in = serialPort.getInputStream();
        OutputStream out = serialPort.getOutputStream();
        try {

            // close the i/o streams.
            in.close();
            out.close();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            // don't care
        }
        // Close the port.
        serialPort.close();
    }
```

When i press the close button my app is just freezing and i eventually get an error in my console saying:

```
A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:

#  EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x00949e69, pid=7568,      tid=4724
#
# JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (8.0_25-b18) (build 1.8.0_25-b18)
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (25.25-b02 mixed mode, sharing windows-x86 )
# Problematic frame:
# C  [rxtxSerial.dll+0x9e69]
```

Can anyone explain what i have done wrong here?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was partially resolved with the below.  I can now successfully close the port once. 
 If i re-open te port and then attempt to close it a second time then the same error occurs.

```
try {

            serialPort.removeEventListener();
            serialPort.close();            
            in.close();
            out.close();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            // don't care
        }
        // Close the port.
        serialPort.close();
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

```
 if(portInUse!=null)
{
    try{
        portInUse.port = (SerialPort)portInUse.portId.open(this.getClass().getName(),TIME_OUT);
                 portInUse.port.setSerialPortParams(baudRate,SerialPort.DATABITS_8,SerialPort.STOPBITS_1,SerialPort.PARITY_NONE);               
                 comConn=this.COM_CONNECTED;
        }

        portInUse.input = new BufferedReader(
           newInputStreamReader(portInUse.port.getInputStream())
        );

        portInUse.output =  portInUse.port.getOutputStream();
        //adding listeners to input and output streams
        portInUse.port.addEventListener(this);
        portInUse.port.notifyOnDataAvailable(true);
        portInUse.port.notifyOnOutputEmpty(true);
        currentPort=portInUse;
    }
```

The Datattype for portInUse:

```
private class CustomPort
{
    String portName;
    CommPortIdentifier portId;
    SerialPort port;
    BufferedReader input;
    OutputStream output;
    Scanner inputName;
} 
CustomPort currentPort=new CustomPort();
```

and the flush function that i used :

```
public void flush()
{
    try {
        this.currentPort.output.flush();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

The close function that i used:

```
public void close(){
    if(currentPort.port!=null){
        currentPort.port.close(); //close serial port

    currentPort.input = null;        //close input and output streams
    currentPort.output = null;
    }
}
```

How to close the port:

```
 this.flush();
 this.close();
```

Have tested it multiple times , repetitively and it works perfectly.

Comment: so your try has no catch ?

Answer (score 0):

So it turns out that version 2.2 of RXTX has a memory leak bug that causes the library to crash on MacOS when you try to close the serial port. The solution for me was to use [nrjavaserial](https://github.com/NeuronRobotics/nrjavaserial) which, among other things, specifically addressed this bug, so that you can close the serial port in MacOS without crashing the library.

I had to remove my install of the rxtx library from my /Library/Java/Extensions folder and of course remove the references to it in my POM file before the nrjavaserial library would work. Then I just used this code to close the serial port and it finally works well.

```
public void disconnectSerial() {
    new Thread(() -> {
        if (serialPort != null) {
            try {
                serialPort.getInputStream().close();
                serialPort.getOutputStream().close();
                serialPort.close();
            }
            catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }).start();
}
```